# Combine Nodejs and Html into React

Tags: html, node.js, reactjs

I am a beginner with React. Just now I finished learning file upload using Node.js, MongoDb, and HTML. I want to know if I want to transform all this code into a React app, do I need to actually combine and change the code for Node.js and HTML? or do I need to separate both files? There is a tutorial that I watch where they actually combine the two.. But I don't know how it works if we already have existing code but want to use it in a React app. When we create a React application, it already has a new template.

[image]

Can I include this file in the react app under src? Also can I separate folder like views, controller and model?

This is the code the main code app .js

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var multer = require('multer');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var path = require('path');

var app = express();

var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination:function(req,file,cb){
         cb(null,'./public/uploads')
    },
    filename(req,file,cb){
        cb(null,file.originalname)
    }
})

var upload = multer({storage:storage});

 mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/pics',{useNewUrlParser:false})
 .then(()=>console.log('connect')).catch(err=>console.log(err))

// making the collection(table) schema
// it contain picspath file for saving the file path
var picSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    picspath:String
})

//collection schema will be save in db by name picsdemo 
// picModel contain the instance of picdemo by which it can manipulate data in it.
 var picModel = mongoose.model('picsdemo',picSchema)


app.set('view engine','ejs');

app.set("views",path.resolve(__dirname,'views'));

var picPath = path.resolve(__dirname,'public');

app.use(express.static(picPath));

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}))

app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
    picModel.find((err,data)=>{
             if(err){
                 console.log(err)
             }
            if(data){
                console.log(data)
                res.render('home',{data:data})
            } 
           else{
               res.render('home',{data:{}})
           } 
    })
    
})

app.post('/',upload.single('pic'),(req,res)=>{
    var x= 'uploads/'+req.file.originalname;
    var picss = new picModel({
        picspath:x
    })
    picss.save((err,data)=>{
         if(err){
             console.log(err)
         }
         else{
             console.log('data',data)
            res.redirect('/')
         }
    })
})

app.get('/download/:id',(req,res)=>{
     picModel.find({_id:req.params.id},(err,data)=>{
         if(err){
             console.log(err)
         } 
         else{
            var path= __dirname+'/public/'+data[0].picspath;
            res.download(path);
         }
     })
})

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000 ;
app.listen(port,()=>console.log(`server running at ${port}`))

module.exports = app;
```

This code is under views/home.ejs

```
<html lang="en">
 <head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
     <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
     <title>Document</title>
 </head>
 <body>
     <h2>Upload Files</h2>
        <form action="/" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
         <input type="file" name="pic"><br>
         <input type="submit" value="Upload">
        </form><br><br><br><br>
    <h2>Download Files</h2>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        image
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        download
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <% for(var i=0; i < data.length > 0; i++) {%>
                 <tr>
                     <td><img src="<%= data[i].picspath %>" style="width:100px; height:100px;"></td>
                     <td>
                         <form action="/download/<%= data[i]._id %>" method="GET">
                          <input type="submit" value="Download">
                        </form>
                     </td>
                 </tr>
                <% } %>
            </tbody>
        </table>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Can I know how it work if I decide to change it into React? I'm still beginner in React. Usually I use HTML in project but I hear a lot using React is a lot better.

Comment: It's very common to keep server code and client code in separate folder structures, but it's certainly not required. While you _can_ organize React file similar to MVC, it's not the ideal way to think about React. I suggest doing some React beginner tutorials and then going from there.

Comment: Hi thank you for replying. If it not burden for you, could you suggest some react beginner tutorial that i can learn from?

Comment: I wish I could, but I honestly don't know. I learned it 8 years ago :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, i strongly recommend you to keep your backend code in separate folder, not in the source file. After you get along with  React, you'll find something called 'NextJS'. When it comes to NextJS, things can be different.

Long story short, keep them in separate folder.

Maybe you can 2 folders like ;

**Client (React-FrontEnd Code)**

**Server (Backend code)**

**UPDATE**
Here is an example of usage ;
[image]

Comment: client and server folder put under src?

Comment: No in the root file. Client folder can contain React App (src,components,hooks etc. files) and Server file can contain Backend files. Naming can be changed ofc